# Приведение к типу имеющему шаблонный параметр

Tags: c++

Имеется список из указателей на абстрактный класс. В списке же лежат указатели на объекты шаблонного класса (конечно унаследованного от базового абстрактного класса). При этом мне нужно дернуть функцию из шаблонного класса через указатель на абстрактный класс, для чего нужно приведения типа - и тут вопрос: можно ли при приведении типа избежать указания шаблонного параметра?

```
template <typename T>
class A : public abst {
   ...
   fun();
}

list<abst *> l;
...

dynamic_cast<A *>(*l.begin()); // вот здесь
```

Comment: `fun` - виртуальная, унаследованная от абстрактного класса? Или произвольная конкретного класса `A`?

Comment: именно класса A - если бы унаследованная, то приведения типа было бы не нужно

Comment: В смысле, указать динамик-каст неведомо к чему? Кстати, чтобы скомпилировалось, надо в последней строчке к А добавить звездочку; а `*l.begin()` — это то же, что `l.front()`.

Comment: Тогда, как я понимаю, нужно указывать тип параметра - потому что к *какому из* типов иначе приводить указатель на базовый тип? Вызов же надо развязывать во время компиляции, раз он не виртуальный...

Comment: @bipll почему это не ведомо к чему? Какой бы тип не был указан в шаблонном параметре - все равно в объекте будет эта функция.

Comment: Да, только компилятор этого не знает и тем более не знает, как это компилировать.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а почему она там будет ? Добавьте ещё один интерфейс, в котором пропишите метод fun(), и кастуйте к нему

Comment: @vegorov это я и так сделал (в качестве временной меры) - мне просто кажется, что должен быть лучший способ, нежели новое наследование.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Ну откуда же? :( Есть два интерфейса, один класса `abst`, другой класса `A<int>`. Чтобы не писать `A<int>`, нужно выделить какую-то общую часть в веере подклассов `abst`, углубить, проще говоря, его интерфейс. Это можно сделать изменив сам класс, либо сделав подинтерфейс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Альтернативный вариант - шаблон [Посетитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Однако, применять его можно только в случае ограниченного количества наследников базового класса. И да, если указанный в вопросе кейс - не единственный.

Comment: Иными слова динамическое против статического, внутреннее против внешнего, углубление против расширения...

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, проблема в непонимании того, чем является шаблонный класс для компилятора. Т.е. ничем. После компиляции шаблонного класса как такого не остаётся. Имеют место быть только специализации (A, A и т.д.), которые были использованы в данной конкретной программе. То бишь шаблонного типа A как полноценного типа не существует. К нему нельзя приводить другие типы. Тем более нельзя кастовать базовый класс (от которого наследуются все специализации шаблона) к A*.

P.S. Это моё понимание шаблонных классов С++, могу быть не прав.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, самое разумное — в комментарии @vegorov:

```
class abst;

struct has_fun: abst {
     virtual void fun() = 0;
};

template<class T> struct A: has_fun { void fun(); };

list<abst *> l{new A};

has_fun *head = dynamic_cast<has_fun *>(l.front());
if(head) head->fun();
```

Comment: Я имел в виду множественное наследование =) Типа `class A: public abst, public has_fun{...` Правда сути это почти не меняет =)

Comment: Ну да, тоже вариант, слева направо они идут или сверху вниз.

Answer (score 0):

Указатели всегда указывают на начало обьекта, а начало обьекта для всех наследников это начало обьекта базового класса(базовый класс может иметь в своем представлении массив, структуру и т. д.) .

Поэтому через указатель базового класса  невозможно обратится к собственным методам обьекта наследника. Базовый класс не имеет представление сколько и каких наследников у него может появится. Это  дает возможность независимости уже написанного кода(классов) от вновь созданного..

Если базовый класс является абстрактным,  то лучше в вашей функции просто вызвать одну из виртуальных функций базового класса. Тогда все будет как вы хотите. Например:

```
using namespace std;
class abst {
public:
    virtual ~abst() = default;
    virtual void f() = 0;
};    
template <typename T>
class A : public abst {
public:
   //...
   void fun() { cout << "show  " << T() << endl; }
   void f() { fun(); }
};
template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
public:
    void fun() {
        cout << "creat  " << T() << endl;
        A<T>::fun();
        cout << endl;
    }
    void f() { fun(); }
};

struct Some_type {
    const string s;
    Some_type() : s("Some_type ") {}
    friend std::ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Some_type& t)
    {
        os << t.s;  return os;
    }
};
int main()
{   
    list<abst*> l;
    A<int>  a;
    B<float> b;
    A<string>  c;
    B<Some_type>  d;
    d.fun();
    l.push_back(&a);
    l.push_back(&b);
    l.push_back(&c);
    l.push_back(&d);
    for (const auto& p : l)
      //  p->fun(); // так не можете
      p->f();        // только так
    return 0;
}
```

И нет нужды нового наследования..

Comment: Указатели не всегда указывают на начало полного объекта. Достаточно рассмотреть множественное наследование.

Comment: Вопрос вообще был не об этом.

Comment: верно, не всегда... Я перебрал

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, вы хотели  вызвать функцию наследника через указатель базового класса, но не создавать еще один базовый. Я предложил в функции наследника вызвать виртуальную функцию базового. О чем тогда вопрос?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вы пишите что через указатель базового типа нельзя обратится к наследнику, а я спрашиваю про приведение типа указателя на базовый класс к указателю на наследника.

Comment: @AnT, вы всегда хорошо излогаете мысли, поэтому я не против, если вы введете свои правки в моем тексте

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, а как же вы собираетесь приводить, если вы не знаете конкретно какому типу принадлежит обьект, чей адрес хранит указатель?...